# How to read array from CDATA string with PHP

Tags: php

I'm getting with cURL string like this:

```
<!CDATA[[
var animals = new Array();
animals[0] = new Animal('Skunk', 10, 15, 'pic1.png');
animals[1] = new Animal('Dog', 17, 11, 'pic2.png');
animals[2] = new Animal('Gorilla', 144, 95, 'pic3.png');
]]>
```

And so on. I've added new lines only to better illustrate structure of that string. The problem is how to get access with PHP to:

- values of array animals (like new Animal('Skunk', 10, 15, 'pic1.png');)
- values of function Animal (like 'Skunk', 10, 15, 'pic1.png')

Simply I want to get in PHP something like this:

```
array{
  [0] => array([0] => 'Skunk', [1] => 10, [2] => 15, [3] => 'pic1.png')
}
```

I hope there is some other solution that explode, preg_match, etc...

Thanks in advice.

Comment: That response string is JavaScript, not PHP. You can use JSON to your advantage here.

Comment: I think he is know about this. Read question man! XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

There is no native way for it. If you have controlling about the called page, i would recommend to output the data as json there and use php's method `json_decode($json, true)`.

If you have no controlling about it, you have 2 possibilitys:

- Parse the String
- Searching for a PHP Javascript Interpreter, execute JS and encode to Json (Maybe to much overhead for this problem)

So the following things will helping you to go the parsing way.

**Therory**

1. Remove `()`
2. Basicly, you will extract all beetween `(` and `)` using this Regular Expression

   /(([^)]+))/
3. You will splitt by `,`

**Praxis**

Not have tested this or checked this for snytax errors, because i have no IDE here:

```
//Remove Initializer Brackets
$dataString = str_replace('()', '', $dataString);

//Your final Animal Collection
$animalCollection = [];

//Find each Animal Definition, which is beetween ( and )
preg_match_all('/\(([^)]+)\)/', $dataString, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {

    //Explode partes of the animal
    $expCollection = explode(',', $match);

    //Create a animal array
    $animal = [];
    foreach ($expCollection as $expPart) {
        //Copy the cleaned animal parts to our array
        $animal[] = trim(str_replace('\'', '', $expPart));
    }

    //fill animal Collection
    $animalCollection[] = $animal;
}

//Show content
print_r($animalCollection)
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, that works fine. Just in foreach you should use $matches[0] instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using regex. Given your sample string:

```
$curl = "<!CDATA[[
var animals = new Array();
animals[0] = new Animal('Skunk', 10, 15, 'pic1.png');
animals[1] = new Animal('Dog', 17, 11, 'pic2.png');
animals[2] = new Animal('Gorilla', 144, 95, 'pic3.png');
]]>";

preg_match_all("/\((.+)\)/", $curl, $match); //this matches each Animal
$result = array();
foreach ($match[1] as $key => $elem){
    $result[] = explode(',', $elem);
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Skunk'
            [1] =>  10
            [2] =>  15
            [3] =>  'pic1.png'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Dog'
            [1] =>  17
            [2] =>  11
            [3] =>  'pic2.png'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Gorilla'
            [1] =>  144
            [2] =>  95
            [3] =>  'pic3.png'
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for help fin. :) Just one thing, regular expression /\((.+)\)/ matches also larger portions of data, that it should.

Comment: It may not be specific enough, it depends on what your other data looks like.